# zxing on Blackberry below 6.0

Tags: blackberry, zxing

I was integrating the barcode scanner app for blackberry using zxing. I am able to create cod file using the build.xml(provided with the zxing package on google code) via command line. But when I add the complete code to a project and build it using eclipse it gives me error as javame module not found. So I have added the javame.jar to the project properties export section(Clicked the javame.jar checkbox). But then I am unable to launch the application. It gives packaging application failed.

Do I need to only build it with the ant or is there a possible way where I can incorporate the zxing package inside my application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the source package to your application instead - don't use a compiled library. I seem to remember there's a single line that needs editing on BlackBerry (something to do with deleting the image taken by the camera, if it throws an exception just comment it out)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. But so I have added the complete package(ie rim folder) and removed the javame.jar then it gives me an error as unable to find com.google.zxing.BinaryBitmap, com.google.zxing.Reader etc. So how should I eliminate these then ?

Comment: Finally did it by adding both core and javame packages. Don't know if its proper way do it.